# Python Multiprocessing outputting entire program

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I don't normally ask questions on the internet nor am i a very good programmer, but i have been struggling with this problem for a while but i cant fathom why it doesn't work. I'm trying to do some maths that i thought i could do in multiple threads, the code below shows my attempt to output the answers that each worker comes to when it is done. I already realise that it is fairly inefficient, what with workers having to wait for others and surely many other problems, but i just want to get this version working. Any help is greatly appreciated

I am running windows 10, python 3.5, with 4 cores and 8 threads and running the program through the console,

Here is my code:

```
import math
from multiprocessing import Process, Lock
import time

lowMult = 0
highMult = 0
dist = "ERROR!"
print("Welcome to this maths test program")
print("We will be testing the nature of closest whole multiple pairs")
print("this test will run for all values 900000 to 900100")
print("press enter to begin")
input()

def worker(name, l, num):
    l.acquire()
    print (name, "Starting")
    l.release()
    found = False
    test = math.sqrt(num)
    if (test % 1) == 0:
        l.acquire()
        print(num, "=", int(test), "*", int(test), "0", "SQRT!")
        l.release()

    else:
        test = int(test)
        for lowMult in range(test, 0, -1):
                for highMult in range(test, (num +1)):
                    if (lowMult * highMult) == num:
                        found = True
                        dist = highMult - lowMult
                        break

                if found:
                    break

        l.acquire()
        if lowMult == 1:
            print(num, "=", lowMult, "*", highMult, dist, "PRIME!")
        else:
            print(num, "=", lowMult, "*", highMult, dist)

        print (name, "Exiting")
        l.release()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    lock = Lock()
    jobs = []
    num0 = 900000
    num1 = 900001
    num2 = 900002
    num3 = 900003
    for num in range(1, 100):
        thread1 = Process(name='worker 1', target=worker, args=("worker 1", lock, num0,))
        jobs.append(thread1)
        thread1.start()

        thread2 = Process(name='worker 2', target=worker, args=("worker 2", lock, num1,))
        jobs.append(thread2)
        thread2.start()

        thread3 = Process(name='worker 3', target=worker, args=("worker 3", lock, num2,))
        jobs.append(thread3)
        thread3.start()

        thread4 = Process(name='worker 4', target=worker, args=("worker 4", lock, num3,))
        jobs.append(thread4)
        thread4.start()

        thread1.join()
        thread2.join()
        thread3.join()
        thread4.join()

        num0 += 4
        num1 += 4
        num2 += 4
        num3 += 4

        while True:
            if thread1.is_alive() & thread2.is_alive() & thread3.is_alive() & thread4.is_alive():
                time.sleep(2)
            else:
                input()
                break
```

Ïn IDLE i get nothing, but i read around that this would happen, but in console i get the first few print commands instead of what i am expecting multiple times:

```
print("Welcome to this maths test program")
print("We will be testing the nature of closest whole multiple pairs")
print("this test will run for all values 900000 to 900100")
print("press enter to begin")
```

I get four of these before another input prompt, at which point the first calculation is done but it seems not to be in parallel, and the second is never finished. from my cpu usage it seems it never starts, but the program doesnt terminate. I have no idea what is going on.

**EDIT:**

It seems as though the actual computing problems lie within my use of `input()` and the definition of 'name'. a few other issues with `.join()` led me to remove them, and the `.is_alive()` check was fixed to use OR instead of AND. Nevertheless, when i run this code in python 3.5 and i get a windows console, I get four copies of this code unintentionally:

```
Welcome to this maths test program
We will be testing the nature of closest whole multiple pairs
this test will run for all values 900000 to 900100
press enter to begin
```

This is what i am currently trying to solve.

Comment: What do you mean "it crashes"?

Comment: I get a traceback, name is not defined, but i believe this to be unconnected. The intended result was to have the workers begin printing the numbers and their factors, also including if they have square roots or are primes. Instead i get repeats of the first four lines of introductory text, that is not part of the workers code what so ever.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Python 2.7, then `input()` will likely "crash", because it is "equivalent to `eval(raw_input(prompt))`" according to the documentation:
https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#input

You could use `raw_input` for the purpose of reading user inputs (actually I don't see the point of asking for a keypress here).

Another problem is that the variable `name` is not defined in the `worker` function.

Also the `thread1.is_alive() & thread2.is_alive() & thread3.is_alive() & thread4.is_alive()` should always evaluate to `False`.

After removing all the `input()`, the output I get is (with Python 2.7) the following, which seems to be the expected result as I understand:

```
Welcome to this maths test program
We will be testing the nature of closest whole multiple pairs
this test will run for all values 900000 to 900100
press enter to begin
(900000, 'Starting')
(900001, 'Starting')
(900002, 'Starting')
(900003, 'Starting')
(900000, '=', 900, '*', 1000, 100)
('worker 1', 'Exiting')
(900003, '=', 611, '*', 1473, 862)
('worker 4', 'Exiting')
(900002, '=', 2, '*', 450001, 449999)
('worker 3', 'Exiting')
(900001, '=', 1, '*', 900001, 900000, 'PRIME!')
('worker 2', 'Exiting')
(900004, 'Starting')
(900005, 'Starting')
(900006, 'Starting')
(900007, 'Starting')
(900006, '=', 6, '*', 150001, 149995)
('worker 3', 'Exiting')
(900004, '=', 28, '*', 32143, 32115)
('worker 1', 'Exiting')
(900007, '=', 1, '*', 900007, 900006, 'PRIME!')
('worker 4', 'Exiting')
(900005, '=', 5, '*', 180001, 179996)
('worker 2', 'Exiting')
...
```

Comment: i realise now that 'name' may have been causing errors, but it doesnt solve the original problem

Comment: Also i am using python 3.5, so input is not the issue sadly. That would have been to easy.

Comment: @TomassWilson Maybe you forgot to press the keyboard (since you have an input() in the innermost loop)?  The output I get seems to be what is expected if I understand your question correctly.

Comment: Also note that the second is the slowest of the first four because 900001 is a prime number.

Comment: This has helped a lot, i am now getting the results i expected, but i still get four copies of the introductory text before any of the workers declare they are starting, and i have no idea why. My current theory is they are for some reason using the main programs code, which might be solved by a 'if __name__ == __main__' but that would still be rather strange.

Answer (score 0):

The first worker crashes due to `name` not being defined *while holding the lock*. That prevents any of the other workers from giving their output, and since they never finish, it also stops the main process from starting up the next round of workers.

To work around this specific issue (and not any of the larger design issues), you should use your lock as a context manager, rather than explicitly calling `acquire` and `release`. This will let it unlock automatically whenever an exception occurs:

```
with l:
    print(num, "=", int(test), "*", int(test), "0", "SQRT!")
```

And:

```
with l:
    if lowMult == 1:
        print(num, "=", lowMult, "*", highMult, dist, "PRIME!")
    else:
        print(num, "=", lowMult, "*", highMult, dist)

    print (name, "Exiting") # this still causes an exception, but it will no longer deadlock!
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems as though most of my questions have been answered. I shall now work on actually optimising the code to run efficiently now that my original problem is solved. It seems as though the workers begin to run all of the code in the parent program, and as such to stop them from printing the introductory text four times over, I have included an `if __name__ == __main__:` before the intro print. It also explains why `input()` was causing issues to begin with. Clearly the heart of the problem i have been having is with my lack of knowledge over how workers work, as I was under the impression they only ran the code of the function they were designated.

Thanks to all who have answered, you have been extremely patient and helpful, i only hope one day i can assist others once my skills have reached a sufficient level